# how to use json data sent from backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, laravel-5

```
$.ajax({
url: '{{ URL('reports/groupsUsersGet') }}',
dataType: "json",
data: {
    group_id : $('#group').val(),
},
success: function(data) {
    <li>"i want to insert variable here"<li>
},
error: function (data) {
    console.log('Error:', data);
}
});
```

controller returns this

```
return Response::json($results);
```

and it gives this

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"name":"user","nick":"user1"}]}
```

how can i acces this in ajax part

Comment: You've got the result of your php script in your `data` parameter in `success` function.
So you can access it with `data.results` etc...

Comment: You may access it using ```data.results[0];```

Comment: In your success function `console.log(data)` to have a look at the structure of response that you are getting and then use the results you are interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the data in ajax, sent from controller like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ URL('reports/groupsUsersGet') }}',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
    group_id : $('#group').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) { // <-------- here data is your variable having json received from backend
        $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
            // Use your results array here...
            $('li.data').each(function(i) {
                $(this).find('span.id').text(val.id);
                $(this).find('span.name').text(val.name);
                $(this).find('span.nick').text(val.nick);
            });             
        });

    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

> You'll get json inside the `data` variable under the `success` section of your ajax call

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Dev - Yup, you're right, I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You first need to access the "results", after that it contains multiple items in the JSON array.

Comment: Now you have only 1 object, what if there are mulitple objects? @SaumyaRastogi

Answer (score 1):

In your `success` method you can access the data returned from the server as:

```
success: function(data) {
  var users = data.results;
  var temptale = '';
  for (var i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        temptale += "<li>Name - " + users[i]['name'] + "<li>"
    }
    // use temptale to insert in your DOM
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryInfoById= function (id) {
        var params = {
            "id": id,
        };

        $.getJSON(prefix + "/queryById.do", params, function (data) {
            $("#name").val(data.name);
            $("#age").val(data.age);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: '{{ URL('reports/groupsUsersGet') }}',
dataType: "json",
data: {
    group_id : $('#group').val(),
},
success: function(data) {

    var array = data.results;
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
     var obj = array[i];
     var id = obj.id;
     var name= obj.name;
     var nick= obj.nick;
     //Add here the data in your UL>LI elements.

}
},
error: function (data) {
    console.log('Error:', data);
}
});
```